Can't create a mysql trigger
I try Restrict Overlapping Time Periods in MySQL on phpmyadmin so new record cannot contains the same pc_id and date because you can't give the same computer few times.
CREATE TRIGGER history_insert_overlap
    BEFORE INSERT ON history
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM history WHERE `NEW.pc_id` =`pc_id` AND `NEW.date` BETWEEN `date` AND `date_return`) THEN
BEGIN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Interval Overlaps Existing Intervals';
END;
END IF;
END;

I got error 1064.

The condition new.start BETWEEN start AND finish does not provide complete overlapping check.

As per Akina's comment, you might want to change your overlap check to NEW.date <= date_return AND NEW.date_return >= date - db<>fiddle

I see,OP perhaps that  new.date is always greater then start date in table. So, new.date between date and date_return is sufficient check.

@user1191247 'null' in "date_return" implies that a pc is still at user's disposal. Before date of record like this there can be a lot of records with filled return_date.

For error 1064 - SQL query syntax: The MySQL error 1064 (42000) is a syntax error that occurs when the SQL statement being executed contains incorrect syntax or violates one or more of the rules of the SQL language. This error message is typically raised when the statement contains a mis-spelled reserved word, incorrect use of quotation marks or a missing clause or operator.
Change
`NEW.pc_id` to NEW.`pc_id`  

And in subquery count(*) always return 1 value. So exists (...) is true. You can not insert any row to table.
See example
CREATE TRIGGER history_insert_overlap
    BEFORE INSERT ON history
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM history 
          WHERE NEW.`pc_id` =`pc_id` 
            AND NEW.`date` BETWEEN `date` AND `date_return`) THEN
BEGIN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Interval Overlaps Existing Intervals';
END;
END IF;
END;

Demo

I managed to create the trigger.  I hadn't had commands DELIMITER $$ CREATE TRIGGER code END $$ DELIMITER ;`. I hadn't realized their purpose and still don't understand why the're important.
